# Does Twitter have search operators like Google?

Tags: twitter, search

Twitter has an [Advanced Search](http://twitter.com/#!/search-advanced) page but can we also use search operators on Twitter like Google?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the following [list](https://support.twitter.com/groups/31-twitter-basics/topics/110-search/articles/71577-how-to-use-advanced-twitter-search) which lets users fine-tune their search query.

[image]